# unexpected syntax: 'missing SEMICOLON at 'if''

Tags: apex

I am trying to debug this error.

> `unexpected syntax: 'missing SEMICOLON at 'if''`

```
public Boolean validateName(String name){
    return if ( name == null || name =='' || name.length() < 3) ? true : false;           
}
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Try removing `if` from your return statement. Ternary operators don't need the `if` part.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 10):

Ternary operators don't need `if` defined. So your return statement should just read:

```
return (name == null || name =='' || name.length() < 3) ? true : false;
```

Or, as [@AdrianLarson](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2995/adrian-larson) pointed out in the comments you could just use:

```
return (name == null || name =='' || name.length() < 3);
```

Which saves a few bytes of code whilst still delivering the same result.

**Edit**

There's a few ways to achieve what you want here, based off of the comments on this post. For instance, from [IllusiveBrian](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12831/illusivebrian):

```
return String.isEmpty(name);
```

This returns a boolean value depending on whether or not the String is empty. Pretty self explanitory!

Additionally, [Sebastian Kessel](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/26224/sebastian-kessel) mentions you can use:

```
return String.isBlank(name);
```

Would also return a boolean value whether or not the String is empty.

The difference between these functions are as follows:

> **isBlank(inputString)**
>
> Returns true if the specified String is white space, empty (''), or null; otherwise, returns false.
>
> **isEmpty(inputString)**
>
> Returns true if the specified String is empty ('') or null; otherwise, returns false.

These are from the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm).

The long story short is that there's a number of ways to handle your specific use case. You can use many functions that will return either true or false.

But, with respect to ternary operators, you just didn't need the `if` part meaning if you, for instance, wanted a ternary operator that returned a String, you'd do so as follows:

```
public static String HelloWorld(Boolean x) {
  return (x) ? 'Hello' : 'World';
}
```

Comment: You don't need the ternary either...

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ah, so `return (name == null || name =='' || name.length() < 3)` would do the same job? That's interesting actually I'd probably not have thought of that. Good to know to golf your code!

Comment: Wow. it is good to know from pros like you guys.

Comment: I prefer `String.isEmpty(name)` to `name == null || name == ''`, myself.  You can also use `String.isBlank()` if you want to also check that the string is not just white space.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this, removing `if` condition.

```
public Boolean validateName(String name)
{
    return ( name == null || name =='' || name.length() < 3);           
}
```

Comment: You can always replace `x ? true : false` with just `x`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, you don't use `if` in a ternary operator. There is also no point in checking both `name==''` or `name.length() < 3`. Instead you can use:

```
public Boolean validateName(String name) {
    return (name == null || name.length() < 3);
}
```

Comment: I would use `String.isBlank` instead of `== null`. Just Saying. :)

Comment: @SebastianKessel nice. I'm a Java programmer who is not familiar at all with the SalesForce Apex language. However, `String.isBlank` checks for null, empty, and whitespace strings. In this case we only want to check for null or length < 3

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I was saying that `String.isBlank` is overkill in this case. We don't need to check for empty or whitespace strings, we simply need to check if for null or less than 3 characters. `String.isBlank` will check for null, empty, and whitespace however we will still need to check for length less than 3.